# Cannot call method 'createRange' of undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs

Help me please.

```
<style>
div.foo{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="foo"></div>


<script>


Ext.onReady(function(){

Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Hello',
    width: 200,
    html: '<p>World!</p>',
    //renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    renderTo: Ext.query('div.foo')
});

});
```

Error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'createRange' of undefined**

I want to insert a widget into the block div.foo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ext.query()` [returns an array](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext-method-query) of DOM elements, so you need to

`renderTo: Ext.query('div.foo')[0]`